# Wordpress log out using URL and redirect to specify page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have one Wordpress installation . i need to log out the user without any indication user is coming from particular URL.Is it possible?

My code:

```
<?php
if($_GET['logout'] == 1)
{
 $redirect_to = current_page_url(); 
 ?>
 <script>
window.location.href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirect_to ); ?>";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I am using above code in my header.php . When the user click particular link with log out parameter value is 1. I need to log out the user without any log out confirmation.

I tried with the above code but its asking the following Confirmation.is it possible to avoid this confirmation.

```
"You are attempting to log out of Learn

Do you really want to log out?"
```

My requesting URL is like this

```
http://localhost/learnwordpresslogout=1&redirect='/learnwordpress/category/category1'
```

I need to log out the user without confirmation and redirect to redirect parameter value URL.Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to do in such way ? You can simply put `wp_logout_url` with **redirect page** as parameter in it. Like `<a href="<?php echo wp_logut_url('your_redirect_page'); ?>"`

Comment: Yes i have some specific Reason that's why I am doing like that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  wp_logout()  function

use the funtion .

```
    if($_GET['logout'] == 1)
    {
    ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
wp_logout();
$redirect = wp_logout_url();
wp_safe_redirect( $redirect  );



     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!!. but I am getting  "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by " ERROR.

Comment: I tried with your above code . in this case I am getting blank page. The log out is happening but Nothing is showing.

Comment: Any way i complete my requirement through your code .Thanks!!

Comment: if it helps tick answer and close the post

Answer (score 0):

```
$logout_var = $_GET['logout'];

if( $logout_var == 1)
{
 // pass wordpress template page id
  wp_logout_url( get_permalink( 4 ) );
  exit;
}
```

Get More Details for `wp_logout_url()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url

Get More Details for `get_permalink();`  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink